# Accessing this object in ES6 inside a promise

Tags: ecmascript-6, this, es6-promise

I have an ES6 class that has a deferred object as an instance variable. I'm trying to access the `this` object inside an angularjs promise, similar to the following, but `this` is undefined, according to babel:

```
class MyClass {

  constructor($q) {
    this.deferred_ = $q.defer();
  }

  myMethod() {
    this.deferred_.promise.then(data => {
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
}
```

Somehow I think I should use two arrow functions to bind `this` to the scope of promise, but I cannot figure out how. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: In this code `this` would refer to the instance of `MyClass` for sure.

Comment: It doesn't. I guess the .promise notation steals this from class scope. I'm not too sure why it doesn't work though.

Comment: Well, **it does** https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%24q)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.deferred_%20%3D%20%24q.defer()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20myMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.deferred_.promise.then(data%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D Please provide an example that demonstrates your problem, your posted code is fine.

Comment: Show us how you are calling `myMethod`. Its `this` is the arrow function's `this`.

Comment: This appears to be an angularjs promise, not an ES6 one.

Comment: @Bergi does that mean angular promises don't support the arrow key way of binding "this"? Should I convert my ES6 class to a regular functio?

Comment: @mohi666: No, this has nothing to do with the promise implementation (I just meant your tags don't match your code). The code (at least the part you've shown) is correct. Either your runtime or your transpiler are faulty.

Comment: ... or you're invoking the method in some weird way.

Comment: Ah my bad. I was trying to test this using chrome dev console. It would stop at the non transpiled ES6 and I guess chrome doesn't support ES6. So it was returning undefined, when I was accessing 'this'.

Comment: *"I guess chrome doesn't support ES6"* It does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what library you're using, you cannot change the context of an arrow function.

```
var x = 5;
var f = ()=> this.x;

f();             //=> 5
f.call({x:3});   //=> 5
z.bind({x:3})(); //=> 5
```

So, as others have commented, in the code you have posted, `this` will refer to the instance of `MyClass`. And there's nothing that could ever change that.

Comment: I was debugging the issue using chrome dev console. I was getting undefined over there. I guess chrome dev console, doesn't support ES6 at all. That's why it was returning undefined.

Comment: @mohi666 I'm pretty sure nothing has a full implementation of ES6 yet, but Chrome (and its dev console) does support *some* (I'd even say *most*) ES6 featues.

Comment: *this will refer to the instance of MyClass. And there's nothing that could ever change that* this line isn't strictly true. `var c = new MyClass; c.myMethod.call({});` would bind the `this` reference of `myMethod` and hence the arrow would use the reference too. Granted that reference would also need a `deferred_` property to reach the arrow but still